# JQuery click event is not being registered on <ul> returned from PHP Script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML page which contains 2 `div`s. In its first `div` a `ul` is populated immediately after page loading using AJAX from a PHP script. And 2nd `div` there is a static `ul`. Now I want that in both `div`s on every `ul` a click event should work. I.e., an alert should come saying that it's clicked.

Here is the PHP code:

```
require_once "../../resources/script/dbconfig.php";

$query = "SELECT * FROM job_case";
$rslt = mysqli_query($link,$query);     

echo "<ul>";

for($i=0;$i<mysqli_num_rows($rslt);$i++)
{
$job = mysqli_fetch_row($rslt);
echo "<li class=\"jobTitle\" id=jon".$job[0].">".$job[1]."</li>";           
}

echo "</ul>";
```

HTML Page:

```
<div class="jobCase" id="govtJobCase">
    <ul>
        <li class="jobTitle" id="jobId">Item A</li>
        <li class="jobTitle" id="jobId">Item B</li>         
    </ul>
</div>        
<div class="jobCase">
    <ul>
         <li class="jobTitle" id="jobId">Item A</li>
         <li class="jobTitle" id="jobId">Item B</li>
     </ul>        
 </div>
```

My problem is it that in first `div` published from PHP, there is no event working but in other static `ul` tag event is working properly.

Comment: can you share the code snippet  where  you're registering click event?

Comment: we can't help you without seeing the jQuery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the event handler on an element around both divs you can update the contents of the element all you want but the event handler stays in tact.

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- the contents of this div is populated using AJAX -->
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.container').on('click', function () {
    // clicks will arrive here even when they originate from ajax loaded content
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should provide us with your jQuery script. But I can help you maybe:

for the event, you should not use `on()` and rather better to stick to `delegate()` since it allows event attachment to the DOM objects which are yet to be created after the initial page load. For instance if your ajax requests returns a `<uL class='sample'></ul>` you can then do:

```
$(document).delegate(".sample", "click", function(){
alert("You have clicked on a newly created <ul>");
});
```

Comment: if it worked you can accept it as an asnwer and vote it up. good to see it works..